# Rails 6.0 is still rendering views even with API only mode enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Does anyone know how to stop rails from rendering devise login views while using config.api_only = true?

I have this in my application.rb file:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
config.load_defaults 6.0

config.filter_parameters += [:server_key]

config.api_only = true
```

Comment: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/4997#issuecomment-450852131

Comment: yeahj i basically have done this. It's not a problem with devise. It's just rendering views for literally everything

Answer (score 1):

Those views are rendered through the controller with `YourController < ActionController::Base` extended to it, this config.api_only only works on newly generated controllers with `YourController < ActionController::API`,
check ur application controller if it has `ActionController::Base` to it, if so change the 'Base' to API  to rectify the error.

Answer (score -1):

This link might be useful https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/API-Mode-Compatibility-Guide

According to this the above link, "*Devise.parent_controller extends from ActionController::API (and not ActionController::Base).*"

Have you tried this?

Comment: It's not just devise views. All views are being rendered.